# Need Help solving Recurrence Problem

Tags: recursion, master-theorem

I have this practice problem that I was given.

I am trying to solve a specific recurrence equation

```
T(n) = 4 when n <= 2 

T(n) = 3T(n/3) + 5 when n > 2
```

how would i go about to solve such a problem since I only really know how to solve Master Theorem and Divide and Conquer using the a and b but don't really know how to solve a problem like this.

I'm trying to get an exact answer as well

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a very basic one. Since you [did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594), we have little to
work with. Let me direct you towards our 
[reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/755)
which cover your problem in detail. This can be solved immediately using [the Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Comment: I suggest you work through the material there, try to solve your 
problem again, and if you're still stuck, edit to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered. 
Good luck!

Comment: Incidentally, I encourage you to [create an account](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/why-register).  Also, if you've created multiple accounts here, I encourage you to [merge them](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).